# React with Redux - callback function is invoked unexpectedly

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I'm not yet a React master, hence my question. Why there is still invoking a parent function if in child component I'm writing new characters in input fields? I want to call parent method only when I clicked Search button in my child component.

Parent component:

```
class MainPage extends Component {
render() {
        let searchOffersBar = (
            <MuiThemeProvider>
                <SearchOffer
                    offersFound={this.props.onOffersFound}
                />
            </MuiThemeProvider>
        );

        let searchResults = (
            <SearchResults
                offers={this.props.offers}
            />
        );

        return (
            <Aux>
                <div className={classes.container}>
                    <Intro/>
                    <div className={classes.contentSection}>
                        {searchOffersBar}
                        {searchResults}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </Aux>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        offers: state.offers.offers
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        onOffersFound: (searchParams) => dispatch(actions.fetchOffersByCriteria(searchParams))
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MainPage);
```

`<SearchOffer>` is my child component with a search section (input fields and button "Search offers"). I want to fill some data in my inputs and then click the button. I though that clicking the button will invoke a method in child component: `onOffersFound`:

```
const searchOffer = props => {

    let currentDate = new Date();

    const [searchCriteria, setSearchCriteria] = useState({
        brand: 'xxx',
        capacity: 100
    })

    const [drawerIsOpen, setDrawerIsOpen] = useState(false);

    const handleToggle = () => setDrawerIsOpen(!drawerIsOpen);

    const handleBrand = (event) => {
        let mergedState = updateObject(searchCriteria, {brand: event.target.value})
        setSearchCriteria(mergedState);
    }

    const handleCapacity = (event) => {
        let mergedState = updateObject(searchCriteria, {capacity: event.target.value});
        setSearchCriteria(mergedState);
    }

    const handleBookingFrom = (bookingFromValue) => {
        let mergedState = updateObject(searchCriteria, {bookingFrom: bookingFromValue});
        setSearchCriteria(mergedState);
    }

    const handleBookingTo = (bookingToValue) => {
        let mergedState = updateObject(searchCriteria, {bookingTo: bookingToValue});
        setSearchCriteria(mergedState);
    }

    return (
        <div className={classes.sideNav}>
            <Button variant={"outlined"} onClick={handleToggle} className={classes.sideNavBtn}>Search</Button>
            <Drawer
                className={classes.drawer}
                containerStyle={{top: 55}}
                docked={false}
                width={200}
                open={drawerIsOpen}
                onRequestChange={handleToggle}
            >
                <AppBar title="Search"/>
                <form noValidate autoComplete="off" onSubmit={props.offersFound(searchCriteria)}>
                    <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
                        <Grid container justify="space-around">
                            <TextField
                                id="brand"
                                label="Brand"
                                margin="normal"
                                onChange={handleBrand}
                            />
                            <TextField
                                id="capacity"
                                label="Capacity"
                                margin="normal"
                                onChange={handleCapacity}
                            />
                            <Button variant="contained" color="primary">
                                Search
                            </Button>
                        </Grid>
                    </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
                </form>
            </Drawer>
        </div>
    );
}

export default searchOffer;
```

`onOffersFound` in my action creator looks like:

```
export const fetchOffersByCriteria = (searchParams) => {
    return dispatch => {
        let queryParams = '?brand='+searchParams.brand + '&capacity='+searchParams.capacity;
        axios.get('/getFilteredOffers' + queryParams)
            .then(response => {
                dispatch(saveFoundOffers(response.data)); --> saves the state
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
            })
    }
}
```

My question is why the above method `fetchOffersByCriteria`  is invoked every time I enter new character in my child component? I want to invoke this method only when I click the Search button in child component. Maybe my approach is bad?

Thanks for all tips!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `props.offersFound(searchCriteria)` is being invoked every `render`. The `onSubmit` prop should be a function to be invoked when submitted. Currently, it's being invoked immediately.

This line:

```
onSubmit={props.offersFound(searchCriteria)}
```

Should be (or something similar):

```
onSubmit={() => props.offersFound(searchCriteria)}
```

Currently, when typing in the `brand` (or `capacity`) field, the `handleBrand` change callback is invoked. This invokes `setSearchCriteria` (a state update) which triggers a re-render of the component. While this component is re-rendering, it's immediately invoking `props.offersFound(searchCriteria)` and passing the return value to the `onSubmit` prop. You likely want the `onSubmit` prop to be a function to be invoked at the time of submitting.

See the [documentation for controlled components](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components) for more de3tails.

Comment: Gosh! You're right! But interestingly onSubmit doesn't work - nothing happens after clicking Search button. It works only when I add invoking my method directly to the Search button like this: <Button variant="contained" color="primary" onClick={() => props.offersFound(searchCriteria)}>
                                Search
                            </Button>

Comment: Is the `Button` rendering a `button` with `type="submit"`? (not, `type="button"`)

Answer (score 1):

```
<form 
  noValidate 
  autoComplete="off" 
  onSubmit={props.offersFound(searchCriteria)}>
```

You are immediately invoking prop and trying to use result returned as event listener. It should be

```
<form 
  noValidate 
  autoComplete="off" 
  onSubmit={() => props.offersFound(searchCriteria)}>
```

instead